# Функция которая считает сумму цифр числа через рекурсию

Tags: javascript, рекурсия

Нужно посчитать сумму цифр в числе использую рекурсию ( 123 = 1 + 2 + 3 = 6). Я решил задачу так , но  в браузере не появляется модальное окно , долго искал где ошибка , нашёл в интернете похожее  решение, но всё равно не могу понять где ошибка и что вообще я сделал не так

```js
function sumNumber(n){
    n = `${n}`;
    let arr = n.split('');
    if ( arr.lenght == 1) {
        return arr[0];
    }
    else {
        return   arr[0] + sumNumber(arr.slice(1));
    }
}
alert(sumNumber(123));
```

Comment: первый раз в функцию приходит число, а в следующие вызовы?

Comment: leng**th**, не lenght. А вообще там бесконечная рекурсия.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Что я сделал не так...

```
function sumNumber(n){ // Название функции не совсем отражает суть
    n = `${n}`;
    let arr = n.split(''); // Массив уже изначально содержит строки, не числа
    if ( arr.length == 1) {
      return arr[0];
    }
    else {
      // arr[0] — строка. Нужно превращать его в число, т.к. в таком виде
      // будет получаться "1" + 2 = "12" — и оно никогда не будет заканчиваться.
      return arr[0] + sumNumber(arr.slice(1));
      // arr.slice(1) — массив строк. Функция должна получать число, а не массив.
      // Массив превращается в строку, получается писец.
    }
}
alert( sumNumber(123) );
```

Правильный вариант:

```js
function sumDigits(n) {
  n = `${n}`;
  if( n.length == 1 ) return +n; // Плюсик перед строкой - превращает её в число.
  
  return +n[0] + sumDigits( n.slice(1) );
  // n - всё еще строка (содержащая число).
  // +n[0] — к первой цифре добавляем результат вызова той же функции 
  // для оставшихся цифр ( slice(1) берет всю строку, кроме первого символа )
}

console.log( sumDigits(1234) )
```

P.s. Такие задачи стоит решать через рекурсию только в учебных целях.

В реальной жизни будет уместно использовать обычный цикл. Например:

```js
function sumDigits(n) {      
  let sum = 0;
  for( let digit of `${n}` ){ // прямо тут, сразу превращая n в строку
    sum += +digit;
  }      
  return sum;
}

console.log( sumDigits(1234) );
```

А, например, используя регулярные выражения, можно посчитать сумму всех цифр в любой строке. `\d` от слова digit, означает совпадение с любой цифрой. `.match()` возвращает массив совпадений.

```js
function sumDigits(n) {
  return `${n}`.match(/\d/g).reduce( (sum, digit) => sum + +digit, 0 );
}

console.log( sumDigits( -1234.5 ) );
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Действительно такую задачу решить без рекурсии было легко,  но сейчас я прохожу рекурсию и с ней у меня большие трудности.

Answer (score 0):

```
const sumNumbersRecursion = (number) => {
  let digit = number % 10;
  if (number > 0) {
    return digit + sumNumbersRecursion((number - digit) / 10);
  }
  return digit;
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score -1):

```js
function sum(x, n){
  if( n == 1 ){
    return x
  } else{
    return x * sum( x, n - 1 );
  }

}

console.log( sum(2, 3)  )
```

Comment: Вы посчитали степень)

Comment: @OPTIMUS PRIME  сейчас попытаюсь исправится ...