# Нужно написать функцию на JS, которая через рекурсию будет выводить сумму цифр в числе

Tags: javascript

Нужно написать функцию на JS, которая через рекурсию будет выводить сумму цифр в числе.

Comment: А где ваша реализация?

Comment: я нашёл ответ на этот вопрос на первый запрос в гугле, запрос: 'сумма цифр числа рекурсия js'
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1041075/331312

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Функция которая считает сумму цифр числа через рекурсию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1041033/%d0%a4%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%81%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%81%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%bc%d1%83-%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%84%d1%80-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%8e)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function indexSum(n) {
        n = `${n}`; 
        if (n.length === 1) {
            return +n;
        }
        result =  +n[0] + indexSum(n.slice(1));
        if (result > 10) {
            indexSum(n - 1);
        }
        return result;
    }
    console.log(indexSum(Math.floor(Math.random() * 50)));
```

Шаблонной строкой мы преобразуем число в строку, а потом через +n опять в число. Через срез отбрасываем символ

Answer (score 4):

Ну или если извращаться и немного усложнить то можно и не думать о вещественных.

```
function sumDigits(n) {
  n = n|0;
  return n<10 ? n: n%10 + sumDigits(n/10);
 }
```

Отрывок [отсюда](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_bitwise.asp)

> JavaScript Uses 32 bits Bitwise Operands JavaScript stores numbers as
> 64 bits floating point numbers, but all bitwise operations are
> performed on 32 bits binary numbers.
>
> Before a bitwise operation is performed, JavaScript converts numbers
> to 32 bits signed integers.
>
> After the bitwise operation is performed, the result is converted back
> to 64 bits JavaScript numbers.

Comment: Нужно использовать приведение к int'у, потому что деление то вещественное

Comment: Все числа в JavaScript вещественные. Но если подать натуральное число то всё будет хорошо.

Comment: n|0 - это такое приведение к целому? Интересное решение.

Comment: А попробуйте сами? Что получиться с вещественным числом

Answer (score 3):

Если не извращаться со строками, то, например, так:

```
function digitSum(n) {
        if (n < 10)
            return n;
        return n % 10 + digitSum(Math.floor(n / 10));
    }
```

P.S. Если подать на вход отрицательное число, то работать не будет, поэтому с отрицательными числами не забывайте использовать модуль.

P.P.S. Дробные вообще не суйте сюда, либо домножайте их на 10, пока они не станут целыми.